# EC2 AMI creation using System Manager Automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-ssm, aws-automation

To create the AMI using System Manager Automation, i tried with the following code:

```
description: Creates a new Amazon Machine Image (AMI) from an Amazon EC2 instance
schemaVersion: '0.3'
assumeRole: '{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}'
outputs:
  - createImage.ImageId
parameters:
  InstanceId:
    type: String
    description: (Required) The ID of the Amazon EC2 instance.
  NoReboot:
    type: Boolean
    description: (Optional) Do not reboot the instance before creating the image.
    default: true
  AutomationAssumeRole:
    type: String
    description: '(Optional) The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform the actions on your behalf. '
    default: ''
mainSteps:
  - name: createImage
    action: 'aws:createImage'
    inputs:
      InstanceId: '{{ InstanceId }}'
      ImageName: '{{ InstanceId }}_BeforePatchingActivity_{{ global:DATE_TIME }}'
      ImageDescription: '{{ InstanceId }}_BeforePatchingActivity_{{ global:DATE_TIME }}'
      NoReboot: 'true'
```

But I am want the local timezone to be added for ImageName and ImageDescription, instead of using global:DATE_TIME, is there any option to achieve that?

I tried global:DATE_TIME, but this variable giving UTC time zone, and expecting for local timezone.

Comment: Local timezone local to who? You wnat to hardcode a timezone ID?